# How to prove all $c_{n},d_{n}$ to be integers if $(n+1)c_{n}=nc_{n-1}+2nd_{n-1}$ and $d_{n}=2c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Let sequences $(c_n)$ and $(d_n)$ be given by
$$c_0=0,\:d_0=1$$
and recursively for $n\ge 1$ by
$$\begin{align}
c_n & =\frac{n}{n+1}c_{n-1}+\frac{2n}{n+1}d_{n-1} \\[2ex]
d_n & =2c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}
\end{align}$$

I'd like to show that all $c_{n},d_{n}$ are integers. (Creat by wang yong xi）

My try： Since 
$$\begin{align}(n+1)c_n & =nc_{n-1}+2nd_{n-1}\\[1ex]
d_n & =2c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}
\end{align}$$
we easily find $$c_{1}=1,\:d_{1}=1,\\
c_{2}=2,\:d_{2}=3,\\
c_{3}=6,\:d_{3}=7,$$
a.s.o.   How to prove that all the $c_{n},d_{n}$ are integers?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialCoefficient.html.

Comment: Looks like $c_n$ can be expressed in terms of trinomial coefficients as lhf suggested.

$$c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor} \frac{n!}{k!(k-1)!(n -2k + 1)!}$$
I derived this by finding the generating functions of $c_n$ and $d_n$. It is sort of ugly and I've doubt this is the intended way for solving this problem.

Comment: How to find this $P(x)=(x^2+x+1)^n?$

Comment: I calculated a few more small values of $c_n$ and $d_n$ and guess that for each natural $n$, $d_n$ is a [Central Trinomial Coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html) (see also The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS), sequence [A002426](http://oeis.org/A002426)), that is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^n$ and $c_n$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ (or, equivalently of $x^{n+1}$) in the expansion), see OEIS, sequence [A005717](http://oeis.org/A005717).

Comment: Hello,But it is said this problem i appears in an exam, that is, there is no reference. Is there any way to find this function, or is there any other way to find this problem

Answer (score 5):

COMMENT.- (Only as information for beginners) Yes, as suggested by lhf and Alex Ravsky, it is practically evident that the $(c_n, d_n)$ correspond respectively to the OEIS-sequences A0057 and A002426 (*see comments above*). The calculation of the first 10 pairs gives

$(0,1),(1,1),(2,3),(6,7),(16,19),(45,51),(126,141),(357,393),(1016,1107),(2907,3139),(8350,8953)$

what is in line with the aforementioned sequences whose integers respond to various interesting problems (geometric, numeric, combinatorial,etc).

In particular the numbers $d_n$ are solution of the recurrence of order two
$$nd_n=(2n-1)d_{n-1}+3(n-1)d_{n-2}$$ whose generating function is
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(1-3x)}}$$ so one has $$f(x)=1+x+3x^2+7x^3+19x^4+51x^5+141x^6+393x^7+1107x^8+3139x^9+8953x^{10}+\cdots$$
Who is not familiar with these methods, can see that the coefficients of the development of the generating function $f$ are exactly the successive values of $d_n$ which we have checked here up to $n = 10$ but this applies to any value of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomials $(1+x+x^2)^n$; the only coefficients that will be non zero are terms whose $x$ exponent is between $0$ and $2n$. Note two other things; firstly they will all be whole numbers and secondly they satisfy $a_{i}= a_{2n-i}$ (i.e they will be symmetrical around the central term).

Now we have define sequences $d_n$ to be the central coefficient and $c_n$ to $1$ off central. So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x+x^2)^{n-1} =1+  \cdots +c_{n-1}x^{n-2}+ d_{n-1} x^{n-1} +c_{n-1} x^{n} + \cdots +x^{2n-2} \\
(1+x+x^2)^n =1+  \cdots +c_{n}x^{n-1}+ d_{n} x^{n} +c_{n} x^{n+1} + \cdots +x^{2n}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the first equation by $(1+x+x^2)$ and consider the coefficient of $x^{n}$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
d_n=2c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Next differentiate both sides of the second equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
n(1+2x)(1+x+x^2)^{n-1} =  \cdots +(n-1)c_{n}x^{n-2}+ nd_{n} x^{n-1} +(n+1)c_{n} x^{n} +\cdots +2nx^{2n-1} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
use the first equation and consider the coefficient $x^{n}$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(n+1)c_n=nc_{n-1}+2_nd_{n-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It suffices to show that the sequences $c$ and $d$ satisfy the initial conditions and remind ourselves of the observation made earlier that all of these values are  whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks,BUt How to find the $(x^2+x+1)^n$?can you some explain? or According to the recursive energy, this parent function can be derived？